# How do I correctly deal with UTF-8 in web responses in my C# code?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

To preface this, the most I know about text encoding I learned from [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html) article.

I am currently writing a C# web system to perform a query on our Google Search appliance, read the results and present them to the user in our own custom UI.   However, there are encoding issues when I am displaying the text summaries to the users.

When I query the GSA directly in chrome/IE/whatever, I get the following response

> Postgame Notes **No**. **8 seed DePaul** vs. **No**. 9 **seed** USF Game 6 – Second
>  Round

In my C# code, I am reading that response with the following code:

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create(LastQueryUrl);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return null;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

When I debug the `content` variable, I see that string converted into:

> USF Game 6 � Second

I am 99% sure that the data coming from the GSA is in UTF-8 format due to other points on their xml stating so, as well as from various tidbits in the documentation.  Even though, if I read the stream using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` instead none of the text is readable.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the text to display correctly?

---

**Edit:** using `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` gives me

> USF Game 6  Second

No question mark, though the dash doesn't show up.

Comment: Your code seems correct. To help us identify your issue, could you temporarily replace your encoding with `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` and paste the rendered string here?

Comment: The reason I’m suggesting ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) is that, even if it doesn’t match the original encoding of your text, it still provides a one-to-one mapping between all 256 byte values and a character, thereby allowing us to infer what byte values you’re actually receiving.

Comment: Updated with that.  It helps, not 100% yet though.

Comment: See the content of `response.ContentEncoding`, Is it really utf-8 ?

Comment: response.ContentEncoding is blank, according to VS's debugger, but contentType is "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"

Comment: Maybe you're actually reading the string correctly in UTF-8 but it is the debugger that does not display it correctly? Some font / locale problem?

Comment: No, because when I display the string in our webpage it is also displaying it with the question mark as well.  It is doing this across all of our company computers.

Comment: The Unicode codepoint for that dash is '\u2013'.  The ISO 8859-1 code page is not able to display that so that can't be it.  It won't be utf8, you wouldn't get the substitution character if it were.  Read it as byte[] first so you at least have an idea what byte value the server is sending for the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try executing this code (instead of your `using` block) and pasting the result again? I’m assuming you’re on .NET 4.

```
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    content = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

**Edit**: I notice that you haven’t been pasting the entire returned string in your posts. Is it because the rest of the string contains confidential data? If so, do not paste the result suggested above.

**Edit<sub>2</sub>**: To get your result to render correctly, you can use `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`; <strike>however, I would suggest you don’t do that, for reasons I shall explain soon.</strike>

**Explanation**: From what I’ve figured, your issue seems to be that the sending party is getting their encodings wrong. You say that their documentation claims UTF-8, which is clearly contradicted from their XML declaration of ISO-8859-1. In reality, the encoding used is neither of the two.

In the hex string you uploaded, the culprit character has a byte value of `0x96`, and occurs in the middle of the sequence `20-96-20`. In both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 (as well as ASCII before them), `0x20` is a space character. However, in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout), `0x96` is a continuation byte, and is [not valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences) unless preceded by a start byte (which `0x20` is not). In [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), `0x96` is a C1 control character and, therefore, *not* a printable character (cannot be displayed to users).

Thus, we may infer that the original character encoding is neither UTF-8 nor ISO-8859-1, but [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), sometimes considered a “superset” of ISO-8859-1 since it replaces the `0x80`–`0x9F` range of control characters by displayable characters. In fact, in Windows-1252, `0x96` is the en-dash character you were expecting.

In consideration of the above, it might be safe to resolve your issue by assuming the Windows-1252 encoding; however, if I were you, I would contact the provider and inform them of this flaw.

```
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
   content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: It's too big to paste, so I uploaded the result to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6753359/gsaBytes.txt

Comment: No, I only pasted the relevant parts above due to brevity.  It's XML consisting of 20 search results that's all going to be displayed to public users.

Comment: I’m analyzing it; gimme a few minutes and I’ll get back to you.

Comment: @KallDrexx - Does this example work, but instead of using `BitConverter.ToString(bytes)`, you use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);`?

Comment: @swDevMan81: that causes the original issue described above (with the question mark)

Comment: @KallDrexx 0x96 is not `-` as in Windows-1252, see [html codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: @L.B: The content is in XML format, not HTML. Additionally, HTML5 [explicitly requires support](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#character-encodings-0) for Windows-1252 (including the `0x80`–`0x9F` range).

Comment: @SwDevMan81: Thanks! :-) I’ve always been fascinated by encodings, and enjoy investigating these interoperability issues.

Comment: Excellent write up, thank you very much.  I wonder if this is a flaw in the Google Search Appliance or if this is more of an issue of how I'm feeding data into it.  Either way, this solution works for now.

Comment: @Douglas Yes it's xml but  seems that it contains some html values in tags which may require a special treatement? (Yes I know it shouldn't but...).

Comment: @L.B: I agree that, either way, it shouldn’t use those characters without at least declaring the proper encoding. If it’d declared the encoding properly and the consumer wanted to extract the HTML4 content from the XML, then I assume it would have been the consumer’s responsibility to convert any characters which are valid in XML but not in HTML4.

Comment: @KallDrexx: You’re welcome! If you have a way of configuring the Google Search Appliance to return UTF-8 instead of Windows-1252, then you should go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 specification requires that documents advertised as `ISO-8859-1` actually be parsed with the `Windows-1252` encoding.

Comment: Well that makes this make a bit more sense